# How to implement OAuth in Worklight 6.2?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I want to implement OAuth in Worklight 6.2. I searched the internet and couldn't find any document related to this. Please help me with the document required to implement in Worklight 6.2.

Comment: It is worth noting that MobileFirst 7.0 now includes inbuilt OAuth support. You may wish to investigate that.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in OAuth support in Worklight 6.2.

The steps to integrate such support are detailed in the following article, written for Worklight 6.1, but suitable for 6.2 as well

[Connect IBM Worklight hybrid mobile apps to LinkedIn services using OAuth](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-worklight-linkedin/)

This article demonstrates doing so for LinkedIn, so you will need to adjust it accordingly for your use case.